# Launch consecutive commands in screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I would like to launch cmd1 and cmd2 in the same screen instance. I want cmd2 to be launched only when cmd1 has completed. I have tried this:

> screen -d -m ./cmd1.bash "$File" && ./cmd2.bash "$File"

but cmd2 is launched outside of the screen. If I understand, && applies to screen but not cmd1. How do I get it to apply to cmd1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I found was to make a new script that has those commands and call that new file.

```
#current.sh
screen -d -m ./both.sh "$File" "$File"


#both.sh
./cmd1.bash "$1" && ./cmd2.bash "$2"
```

Tested on Screen 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06.